# Mongodb driver class for Logstash input plugin JDBC

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc, logstash, logstash-input-jdbc

I am using Logstash to replcate a database from MongoDB to Elasticsearch using Logstash 6.0.0, here is my config file:

```
input{
    jdbc{
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/driver/mongodb-driver-3.6.1.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://mongo:27017/DevDb"
        jdbc_user => ""
        statement => "*"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => 'http://user:xxxx@elasticsearch:9200'
    index => 'mongo'
 }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am using the official MongoDB java driver, downloaded from this link: [Mongo java driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/), but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
Exception: LogStash::ConfigurationError
```

So what class name should I use?

Comment: The MongoDB driver has a number of dependencies that you also need to include for it to work, see also http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 3):

```
input {
  jdbc {
       jdbc_driver_library => "mongojdbc1.3.jar"
       jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
       jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://username:password@mongourl:27017/database_name?authSource=admin"
       jdbc_user => ""
       jdbc_password => ""
       schedule => "* * * * * *"
       statement => "db.collection_name.find({},{'_id': false});"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "vm_server_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

This config worked for me and the driver that you have in the config file does not look like the jdbc driver. So look for the jdbc jar. https://bitbucket.org/dbschema/mongodb-jdbc-driver/src/master/

And if you are querying from mongo your json format might not look the same as it is in mongo.
For that you can check the link
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/issue-using-logstash-input-jdbc-to-load-mongo-data/174914